I moved a recovery partition on an MBR computer with both Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed, and after restart it shows the Grub Recovery screen
I had Linux Mint dual booted alongside Windows 10 on my MBR computer, and both were working fine. While on Windows, I unallocated a Windows Recovery partition that was on the left, and it moved to the right.
I continued using Windows 10 normally for a while, but when I rebooted, it was on the GRUB recovery screen where it stated something along the lines of no such partition found - entering recovery mode. I have a Linux Mint ISO burned to a USB that I can boot from. Is there any way to fix GRUB from the USB?
Information that may be helpful from the Linux Mint ISO USB terminal:
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb99eb1c8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  19720191  19718144   9.4G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2  *     19720192  19924991    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        19924992 765333810 745408819 355.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       765847550 976771071 210923522 100.6G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       975564864 976771071   1206208   589M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


Disk /dev/sdb: 58.59 GiB, 62914560000 bytes, 122880000 sectors
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd548b2ee

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         64   5990687   5990624  2.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2          8364     18475     10112  4.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       5992448 122879999 116887552 55.7G 83 Linux

$ sudo blkid

/dev/sda2: LABEL="System Reserved" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="203EF7303EF6FD9A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b99eb1c8-02"
/dev/sda3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="9CD4F889D4F86744" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b99eb1c8-03"
/dev/sda5: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="A85836195835E6AA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b99eb1c8-05"

/dev/sdb1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-01-09-12-59-13-00" LABEL="Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon 64-bit" TYPE="iso9660" PARTUUID="d548b2ee-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="659D-4321" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="d548b2ee-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="writable" UUID="0e267242-0fcb-4a0c-9635-817cf3c85d8b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d548b2ee-03"

/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="b99eb1c8-01"

$ sudo lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   9.4G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 355.4G  0 part /media/mint/9CD4F889D4F86744
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   589M  0 part 

sdb      8:16   1  58.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   2.9G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdb2   8:18   1   4.9M  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   1  55.7G  0 part /var/log


Simply restore the drive image made before making that change.
